# Format a USB stick completely

Tags: partitioning, usb, usb-drive, format

How can I delete **all data** that is on stick?

For example I have this problem:

My stick has two partitions `A` (3.7 GB) and `B` (330 MB). How can I merge the two partitions in one and to delete all data that they contain?

I guess they have read-only properties... How can I force deleting them?

I see this in GParted:

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

How to erase / delete / blank or wipe a disk

I’m sure there are other methods, but the one I prefer to use is the one that uses `dd` to copy zeros, or random data in the file system I want to wipe.

So, run this command if you want to erase your… let’s say microSD card.

Suppose it is mounted on `/dev/sdd1`:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdd1
```

If you do not want to wait too much, you can fill the partition with zeros instead of random data:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd1
```

Both are secure, but IMHO the first one may be better, but of course I can be wrong.

Once again, be sure to double check, or better triple check on which partition you are going to apply this, you will not be warned by Linux, and the result can not be undone.

A good practice could be to first make an image of the disk and then wipe it. If you want to proceed that way, do this.

```
dd if=/dev/[partition-to-wipe] of=/tmp/backup.img
```

Then wipe it

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/[partition-to-wipe]
```

You can then recover the data by doing

```
dd if=/tmp/backup.img of=/dev/[partition-to-wipe]
```

Info taken [from this site](http://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/privacy-erase-blanck-or-wipe-your-disk-or-usb-memory-stick.html).

Comment: I get: `dd: opening ‘/dev/sr1’: Read-only file system`.

Comment: For `/dev/random` vs `/dev/zero`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499409/dev-zero-or-dev-random-what-is-more-secure-and-why) - @Johnツ, you need to use the command with `sudo` in front.

Comment: Urrr... Doesn't restoring the image restore anything that was removed by wiping it with `/dev/random` or `/dev/zero`?

Comment: @wilf Nope. `/dev/zero` is just a place where data gets dumped and destroyed. If you reboot, nothing will be left, might even be before!

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness, I meant it backups the image byte for byte, wipe the USB stick, and then restores it...

Comment: @wilf True. I think he just included that *in case* John ツ wants to restore the data in case he accidentally didn't want to wipe that stick.

Comment: Didn't think of that....

Comment: The question is about deleting all the partitions on a disk, this "answer" tells us how to erase the data inside one of those partitions.

Answer (score 7):

Just use [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/).
[image: GParted]

Unmount all the partitions on the USB stick, and then delete them. You can then create partitions as you like. The is some documentation [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/documentation.php) if you need any.

This should effectively wipe any partitions. - remember to click this green button, or it won't do anything:

[image]

---

If you just want to wipe it, you could also find the device name in `sudo fdisk -l` in terminal, and then run:

```
sudo dd /dev/zero /dev/sdX1
```

Where `sdX1` is the name and partition number of the device, which you can find in GParted or `fdisk`. This is not that necessary if you just use GParted, but you may need to use GParted afterwards to reformat it anyway... [image: smiley]

Comment: Seems that the other partition is not visible... :-( How can I merge it?

Comment: If is not visible, it is probably not there in the first place. Just delete everything, and some new partitions *(FAT32 is best if you want it to work with Windows as well)* - **Having copied anything you want off first** - :-)

Comment: I can see it in Nautilus and access its files. After formatting the USB drive they are still there.

Comment: Is this a common-or-garden USB stick? Wiping the partition table would get rid of everything as well. Note that you have to click the tick in GParted before it does anything...

Comment: It contains a read-only partition... How can I delete or merge it?

Comment: Did you format on another OS? Some filesystem types only mount as read only. But, deleting it in GParted should delete it.

Comment: I received it from someone. That partition doesn't appear in GParted...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12006/discussion-between-john--and-wilf)

Comment: I believe the last command should be `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Start up gparted via the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and entering `sudo gparted`

[image: terminal].

Once you do that gparted will start.

[image: gparted starting]

The USB stick should show in the disks area (upper-right-hand corner) as something like `/dev/usb` or `/dev/sdb`. Make ***sure*** the disk selected is the USB stick, the following steps will wipe ***ALL*** data on the selected disk.

1. Go to `Device`>`Create Partition Table` This window will come up:

[image: new partition window]

click <kbd>Apply</kbd> . You may have to also start this process by clicking the check-mark button.

This will create a new partition table and will make the data unrecoverable by most people.

Comment: You may want to use `gksudo gparted` instead of `sudo`...

Comment: Depends on personal preference I guess.

Comment: Nahhh... Its more that some want it that way on this forum, and like editing answers to be the way they want them.